# Assinging a new value to item in list during for loop doesnt work?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, variable-assignment

I have a list of items. In a for loop i check if the item is 3. And if it is 3 then it should change the 3 to a 2. These are the two ways that came to my mind using a for loop. But only the last one does work.

Is there a way I can make the first for loop work without losing its "pythonic" style?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

for num in a:
    if num == 3:
        num = 2
# -> [1, 2, 3]



for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 3:
        a[i] = 2
# -> [1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: The pythonic solution is not to modify the list in-place, but to create a new copy of the list with updated values.

Comment: You'll have to make a fundamental design decision. Do you want to modify the list in place or create a copy?

Comment: Your second snippet is definitely a reasonable, if not perfect solution.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to assign to a bare name (`num`) and have it affect a container (list `a`). You need to use an index. Although, it is more Pythonic to use `enumerate`:

```
for i, num in enumerate(a):
    if num == 3:
        a[i] = 2
```

Another option is to use a full-slice assignment to totally overwrite the contents of the list from a generator expression:

```
a[:] = (2 if num==3 else num for num in a)
```

Comment: wow, didnt know `enumerate` existed, super helpful thank you

Comment: The full slice assignment with the generator comprehension can just be replaced by simple list comprehension (which is more efficient by memory and speed): `a = [2 if num == 3 else num for num in a]`

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at this code:

```py
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    ...
```

In the for loop, the `[1, 2, 3]` is a list object.  The `i` is just a variable that holds a pointer (basically a reference to the data).  When you do an operation like `i = 3` in the loop, the variable `i` is set to hold the number `3`, but the actual list is not changed.  List comprehension can be used for what you're trying to accomplish:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
l = [2 if num == 3 else num for num in a]
# note that this is a ternary operator in a list comprehension
```

If you wish to use a `for` loop, then then `enumerate` method with index assignment will do the trick:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i, num in enumerate(a):
    if num == 3:
        a[i] = 2
```

You can also do it manually like so:

```py
i = 0
for num in a:
    if num == 3:
        a[i] = 2
    i += 1
```

Note that:

- list comprehension creates a new list (and doesn't edit the old one)
- the enumeration method I showed above does edit the original list (but may be slower, this is based on your machine though)
- the final option I put just to illustrate what the `enumerate` method does and to show that it is an option

Answer (score 2):

To modify in-place, this is perhaps more Pythonic:

```
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if n == 3:
        a[i] = 2
```

This may also be preferable if you have a lengthy test for how an item is replaced, such that a list comprehension may be unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Try a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [2 if num == 3 else num for num in a]
>>> a
[1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If not a list comprehension, you could do use an enumeration:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
for count, num in enumerate(a):
    if num == 3:
        a[count] = 2
```

A map also works (seriously just use a list comprehension), but it's a bit less pythonic (lambdas are also confusion to some people):

```py
a = [1,2,3]
a = list(map(lambda num: 2 if num==3 else num, a))
```

Another thing you can do is, if the variable you're iterating over is some object with a method containing side effects (like a setter), you could use that in-place. For example, imagine I have some `myInteger` class that inherits from `int` with a method that lets me set some value. Let's say it's something like:

```py
myInt = myInteger(5)
print(myInt.value)
>> 5

myInt.set_value(6)
print(myInt.value)
>>6
```

This would give you the interface you're looking for:

```py
for num in a:
    if num == 3:
        a.set_value(2)
```

The trade-off being that you're writing a weird class to do this, which will lead to confusion in the future.

Comment: `list(map(lambda))` is two layers deeper than it needs to be. Really, just use a comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, list comprehensions are the way to go there. But it's an option at least!